# Fetch response not logging to Console

Tags: rest, express, fetch-api

Im attempting to fetch from my localhost URL but the all the console.log() except for "done" do nothign and my .catch isnt receiving an error

```
fetch(tURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(post),
        mode: 'cors',
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
          }
        form.reset();
      console.log("Response received from server");
      console.log(res.json);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(npost => {
      console.log("Parsing response as JSON...");
      form.style.display = '';
      console.log(npost);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

    console.log('done');
    
})
```

I put several debugging logs to see what was being reached but i get nothing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is because of a syntax error, the `})` at the end of your file should not be there, I think it is because the formatting is fairly difficult to read. If you write a `.then` statement between `catch` and `console.log` it will work fine. If you count the parenthesis between the `fetch` and the end, there is an extra set to close a block that doesn't exist. If you delete the `})` at the end, your code will work, however the log statement will run before the fetch is complete; which I assume you don't want. To solve this, delete that `})` and add this to the end of the chain:

```
.then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Original code

```
fetch(tURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(post),
        mode: 'cors',
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
          }
        form.reset();
      console.log("Response received from server");
      console.log(res.json);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(npost => {
      console.log("Parsing response as JSON...");
      form.style.display = '';
      console.log(npost);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

    // This is where the error is, the catch statement was the last "block" in the callback chain, so the `})` is closing a "block" that doesn't exist.


// Delete the semicolon above and uncomment the next line to fix
// .then(() => {
    console.log('done');
    
})
```

Comment: sorry this isnt my full code the last parentheses bracket is completing a different block